# Wordpress apply add_filter('user_has_cap') when update a post

Tags: wordpress

WordPress version `5.4.2`

I have a custom filter to modify editor capabilities temporarily when he tried to update a post,
the filter is working when the editor tried to update an existing post. but there is a problem after the editor click the update button,

after its finish the update, the button will be showing `submit for review` but what I want is stay with `update` button, because what I'm trying to do is,

when editor upload a new post, admin must be approve it first, then after that the post that has been approved can be edited and published by the editor, no need for the admin permission anymore.

and here is my filter.

```
add_filter('user_has_cap', function ($allcaps) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) return $allcaps;
    
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = (array) $user->roles;
    if (!in_array('editor', $roles)) return $allcaps;
    global $pagenow, $post;

    if (in_array($pagenow, array('post.php', ))) {
        $post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);
        if ($post_type == 'post') {
            $allcaps['publish_posts'] = 1;
        }
    }

    return $allcaps;
}, 3);
```

but and what I've tried for the ajax request.

```
add_action('pre_post_update', function($post_ID, $data) {
    add_filter('user_has_cap', function ($allcaps) {
        ... // exactly the same with the filter code
    }, 3);
});
```

so how to achieve what I want for after editor make the update on existing post? so the button will be stays in `update` not `submit for review`. thankyou

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but on my fresh WP install if i create a new editor user i can edit any post w/o the need for them to go in review mode. Do you have some plugin/code that changes this behaviour or i didn't understand the question?

Comment: Sounds like your editors should actually be contributors?     Or is it that they need approval to create a post, but once it is created they can edit it and type whatever they want ?

Comment: @DiegoCavalletti sorry if my explanation not clear enough, what I want is when `editor` create a new post and want to publish its need an admin approval, but when `editor` edit existing post, they can update it by themselves without admin approval to publish it

Comment: @anmari yes, they need approval when creating a post, but when edit an existing post, they can edit it and publish it by themselves without admin approval. 

and the code above is not working only when after the `editor` edit the post, when they edit & publish it, the button will be automatically changed to `submit for review`. but the their edit is already published, the problem is some people think that their post is not updated so they click the `submit for review` button then the post going to drafted.

Comment: May I ask the business use description?  You may be able to exactly what you want just using capabilities via user role editor & for custom post types.

Comment: @anmari its a property website, I already tried to use only capabilities but I can't achieve it, because the capabilities that may publish the post is `publish_posts` only, and its doesnt use custom post types. thats why I need to change it temporarily when edit or create new post

Comment: I agree it is not doable with capabilities.  I think it is also going to be tricky to do it the way you are thinking now.   
From a business point of view, would this work:   approver creates a post, assigns the authorship to the property owner, possiily with a state 'pending review' and THEN the property owner can edit & publish updates as they please.  Basically they are never allowed to 'add new', but once a post exists assigned to them as author, they can update and do as they wish?

Comment: @anmari yes, but the website owner didnt want that, because `editor` is a `listing agent` in this case, and `administrator` is the `manager`, so the manager didnt want to upload property by themselves, he just want to check the post, if its OK, then he will publish it to the website, otherwise it'll get pending until the listing agent fix it,

Comment: And the manager is allowed to edit & publish without any checks?   My point being that the manager could still do whatever the admin is worried about them doing?

Comment: @anmari yup, because manage position is `administrator` in WP, and listing agent is `editor`, `author` role for `sales agent` that found the property by themselves, and there is a `super administrator` role as well that have full capabilities for anything. Maybe its looks like kinda weird for you and the truth is weird for me as well, but this is what they wants and its already going for 10 years

Comment: Editors / Listing agents can access and edit all posts (not just the ones they created?) as per normal wordpress

Comment: yes they are, because they are listing agents, and listing agents can edit all posts, so do you have any idea to make this working?

Comment: Hi Krishna, I actually spent some time playing with this, either 1) temporarily downgrading access (removing capability) , but then of course problems with what wp shows them everywhere, expecting they can publish,    or 2) temporarily upgrading a lower role so that they can edit their  published posts, then one finds different set of problems. eg in making edit buttons show in the lists of posts etc.  I briefly looked at using the 'transition_post_status' actions but the challenges are similar and it would not be an answer to your current question.

Comment: You may need to approach this a different way. EG: There are plugins that limit the number of posts that a user can create.  They are bit old (as in not recently updated) and may need deprecated functions to be cleaned up.  At a quick look, this one worked "Bainternet Posts Creation Limits" . User can never 'add new' or create their own, but can then edit any published posts that they are the author of (or anyones if they are editor).     A form could then be used for them to submit their first draft for review?  OR a different post_type used and admin switches post type when approving.

Comment: @anmari yeah, this is what I actually already do, i temporarily add the `publish_posts` capabilities from the user, without affecting the database, that's why i'm using `user_has_cap` filter which makes me able to enable `publish_posts`, and I already try with remove the capability instead add it to the user. but theres a problem with wordpress ajax, which when someone create a new post, and make it as a draft, then they can publish it by themselves without approval. `in_array($pagenow, array('post.php', ))` this is the code to check if current page is create new or edit.

Comment: @anmari thanks for the suggestion with bainternet, and I just checked, but thats not what I need. I appreciate it tho.

Comment: Khrishna, the suggestion was for an alternative solution using something like that plugin as a part of of the solution.  Use it to set new post limit to 0. Users can still edit already published posts.  Then have them submit their ‘new’ listings either via a form (& save as pending) OR using another post type ‘add new’ where that post type never appears on the front end.  Then admin can ‘approve’ the listing by changing the post_type to ‘post’ & voila it is publisher &editable.